# Can't separate methods from MainActivity class

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-context, android-alarms

Created new Java class where trying to implement `AlarmManager` class method. I want to create functionality for creating, editing and deleting alarms. Everything has worked fine while all the code was in `MainActivity` class.

New class has constructor where context is passed. While application builds successfully, the alarm is not working.

I'm calling setShowDataEvent method at MainActivity:

```
AlarmController alarmController = new AlarmController(this);
alarmController.setShowDataEvent(startTime, finishTime);
```

Here is AlarmController class:

```
private final String TAG = "AlarmController";

Context context;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
AlarmManager mAlarmManager;


public AlarmController(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    this.mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void setShowDataEvent(long startTime, long finishTime){


    newAlarmIntentData(startTime);
    mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, startTime, pendingIntent);

    newAlarmIntentData(finishTime);
    mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC, finishTime, pendingIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "setShowDataEvent has been executed");
}

private void newAlarmIntentData(long time){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("showData", true);
    intent.putExtra("time", time);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

Comment: I' don't where you call the AllarmController contructor. Try passing the context in setShowDataEvent method and not in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks christian mini for response. I am going to call AlarmController class once and use its methods.

Comment: If you use AllarmController class once I suggest to make a static or singleton class and put a fresh context as parameter in static method of this class.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "not workIng", but you're using the same `PendingIntent` – as far as the system is concerned – for both alarms, so the second overwrites the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After moving `AlarmManager` to constructor and restarting `AndroidStudio` all begin to work.  I have added same data to intent, so now there are a two different `PendingIntent`'s.

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("myalarms://" + time));
```